# Is it secure to blindly trust image urls and output them into html img tags on a site? Can it be used to inject code?

Tags: html, image, security

I have to process a feed from a data provider, in this feed they provide us with image URL, currently we download them and store them in our own media server, but I was wondering if it was safe to simply get the url and output it directly in the html as the src attribute of an img tag.

My main concern is if this exposes us to the possibility of someone placing files under that URL which would could run malicious scripts/ do something other than render an image (or fail to render an image if it isn't one/doesn't exist, which is fine)

Will the img src attribute only render images, or will it download the file specified in the URL to the user's browser regardless of what it is?

I can verify at the import stage that the URL at least appears to be a valid image URL, so it would only ever have .jpg or whatever as an extension, but obviously this might still allow them to redirect to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image URLs can of course point to scripts (with some URL rewriting) but there's no risk to get a script run from an image load. URL data is treated as binary image data, not as runnable text/script.

If it's a script, for your browser it's nothing more than a corrupted image file.
So, no code injections risk. At least this is what I know.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was hoping. I take it this behaviour is browser specific? If so, do you know if it is backed up by specification, or just by the fact that doing anything else is clearly stupid?

Comment: I've made up an edit.

If it's a script, for your browser it's nothing more than a corrupted image file. So, no code injections risk.

Comment: note that image url could be like "http://your-domain.com/drop-db.php?name=users#.jpg", which will call your script to delete some data on your server, and any authorized user will execute this action.